# Sharepoint 2010 downloads html instead of opening from SiteAssets

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I uploaded an html page into the SiteAssets of SharePoint 2010.  When I click on it or type the url in it tries to download instead of opening it in a browser.  Should I put the html file somewhere else?  Do I need to create a new site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html is not a safe file. 
You have 3x options here

1. rename the file to aspx and watch it work
2. add the text/html to safe files on the SharePoint farm. Google it..
3. Enable Permissive file handling on the web application (rely not recomanded)